# Cannot read properties of undefined error, when trying to access depths in a data set

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

code

```
if (interaction.commandName === 'comp-scrambles') {

        let datascrams = {};
        
        fs.readFile('scrambles.json', 'utf8', function(err, rawData){
            let datascrams = rawData;
        })
        const replyscrams = datascrams[interaction.options.getString('cube')]['scrams'];

        interaction.reply(replyscrams);
 
    }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "3x3": [
    {
      "scrams": "das"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expect it to go to my JSON file and go in the cube depth, and then the scrambles and take that. But it says

````
C:\Users\Logan Alt\OneDrive\Desktop\KinchServer Comp Bot\src\index.js:479
        const replyscrams = datascrams[interaction.options.getString('cube')]['scrams'];
                                                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrams')
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Logan Alt\OneDrive\Desktop\KinchServer Comp
``` which is the error message
````

Answer (score 0):

The json you used as an example has "scrams" inside an array,

```json
{
  "3x3": [ //here
    {
      "scrams": "das"
    }
  ]
}
```

that would make your variable be:

```js
const replyscrams = datascrams[interaction.options.getString('cube')][0]['scrams'];
```

added `[0]`, or any index you need, after `datascrams[interaction.options.getString('cube')]` and before `['scrams']`

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your code this way:

**Code**

```js
if ( interaction.commandName === 'comp-scrambles' ) {
    // Read File Sync
    const datascrams = fs.readFileSync( 'scrambles.json', { encoding: 'utf8' } ) || {};

    // Get Cube Variable
    const interactionCube = interaction?.options?.getString('cube') || null;

    // Chain ands to determine if structure exits
    const replyscrams = datascrams && datascrams[ interactionCube ] && datascrams[ interactionCube ][0] && datascrams[ interactionCube ][0].scrams || null;

    // Send reply
    interaction.reply( replyscrams );
}
```